# How to mimic private and public constructor overloads in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, private

I have a class that is intended to be constructed from two different places, outside of the class, and inside of the class.

The module that the class is defined in provides an object, which the class captures in its closure environment.

From inside the class (e.g. method calls), the class is constructed with the object.

Here's what it might look like in JavaScript:

```js
const private_accessor = ...;

export class T {
    create() {
        return new T(private_accessor);
    }

    constructor(key) {
        if (key === private_accessor) {
            // trusted call
        } else {
            // outside callee
        }
    }
}
```

We could type the constructor as `constructor(key?: object)`, but, in reality, that doesn't reflect how the class is meant to be used.

What I consider to be the intuitive answer would be this:

```js
const private_accessor: object_type = ...;

export class T {
    create(): T {
        return new T(private_accessor);
    }

    private constructor(key: object_type);
    public constructor();
    constructor(key /* object_type? */) {
        if (key === private_accessor) {
            // trusted call
        } else {
            // outside callee
        }
    }
}
```

Since the private overload is an implementation detail, and wouldn't work from an external callee anyway, there is no reason to expose the type overload.

But this isn't allowed by TSC.

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be nice to have multiple call/construct signatures with different visibility, that's just not supported by the language.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9592) which was closed as a design limitation: it doesn't seem to be an common enough use case to warrant the extra effort and compiler complexity.

---

Instead, I'd suggest that you consider having a separate set of external-facing and internal-facing interfaces, where the external ones only contain "public" functionality, and the internal ones also contain "private" functionality.  When you `export` your values/types, only expose the public functionality:

```
class T {
  create(): T {
    return new T(private_accessor);
  }

  constructor(key?: object_type) {
    if (key === private_accessor) {
      // trusted call
    } else {
      // outside callee
    }
  }
}

// public version of T 
const Tpublic: new () => T = T;

export { Tpublic as T }; // renamed
```

Here the internal version of the `T` class can be constructed both ways, but you are exporting it as a something with only a no-arg [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  Other code that imports this library is therefore prevented from using the "private" constructor:

```
import { T } from "./lib";

const t = new T(); // okay
t.create(); // okay

new T("something"); // error!
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~ Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts
```

[CodeSandbox link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-8ow6d?file=/lib.ts:0-342)

Comment: Yes, I've seen their issue, Ryan didn't think that it was a common enough case to implement it. But thanks, that type cast & rename could probably be dropped in place of any code where this sort of type interface is needed.